# Let $I=[a,b]$ and $f: A \rightarrow R$ continuous on $I$. Let $f(a)>0 $ and $f(b)<0$. If $U=({x\in I: f(x)<0})$ and be $u=sup(U)$, show that $f(u)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $I=[a,b]$ and $f: A\rightarrow R$ continuous on $I$. Let $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0$. If
$U= ({x\in I: f(x)<0})$ and be $u=sup(U)$, show that $f(u)=0$.

So here's my thoughts on this:
As a consequence of intermediate value theorem (Bolzano), if a function is coninuous on
$I=[a,b]$ then, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$. Then as an observation: We have $U={(x\in I: f(x)<0)}$ and with $f(b)<0$ then $u=Sup(U)=0$, so we can affrim that $u\in I$. I have no other ideas on this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question you are asked gives a proof of the intermediate value theorem, so I would expect you are not supposed to use that theorem in your answer. Since I is closed, $u \in I$, so $f$ is continuous at $u$. Now $f(u)$ is either $>0$, $<0$, or $=0$, and so you need to show the first two options cannot be the case for $u=\mathrm{Sup}(U)$. If, for example, $f(u)>0$, what can you say about $f(x)$ for $x$ very close to $u$?

Comment: Would $f(x)$ approaches $0$?

Comment: Informally speaking, continuity means that if $x$ is close to $u$ then $f(x)$ is close to $f(u)$. If $f(u)>0$ what should that tell you about $f(x)$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $u$? Is that consistent with $u=\mathrm{Sup}(U)$?

Comment: I don't get it, I don't know

Comment: @wflewis is of course correct that you need $U=\{x \in I: f(x)>0\}$ if $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)<0$, since $\text{sup}\{x\in I: f(x)<0\}=b$ if $f(b)<0$. Assuming this, if $f(u)>0$, then $u \neq b$ so $u<b$, and for all $x$ sufficiently close to $u$, you must have $f(x)>(1/2)f(u)>0$. But then for $x>u$ sufficiently close to $u$, $f(x)>0$, contradicting the definition of $u$.

Comment: The OP is incorrect. $u=\sup U=b$, and $f(b)<0$

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem as stated is incorrect. As $f(b) < 0$, we see that $b \in U$. As $U \subseteq [a,b]$, we see that $\forall x \in U: x \leq b$, so $\sup(U) = u \leq b$, but as $b \in U$ we see that $u = b$. But then $f(u) = f(b) < 0$.

I think possibly the problem should require that $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$. In that case, let $\{u_n\} \in U$ such that $u_n \to u = sup(U)$. As $f$ is continuous, we see that $f(u) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(u_n) \leq 0$. From here you can check for yourself that $f(u)$ cannot be less than $0$, so it must be equal to $0$. Hint: Assume $f(u)$ is  less than zero. Note that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $f(u + \varepsilon) > 0$ (why?), and try to see how that violates continuity.

Comment: So I assume that $Sup(U)=0$ and that's why $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(u_n)\le 0$

Comment: Ah, I'll elaborate on that step. $Sup (U)$ is the supremum over a set, so it will give you can element of $I$. 

The reason that $\lim f(u_n) \leq 0$ is because, for each $n$, $f(u_n) < 0$, and the limit of negative numbers is (necessarily) non-positive (i.e. $\leq 0$). If you're comfortable with epsilon-delta proofs you should be able to show this directly! If not let me know.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. Can you show?

Comment: I'll prove this as a general statement. Let $a_n < 0$ be a sequence of negative real numbers which limit to $a$ (i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$).

Suppose FSOC that $a > 0$. As $a_n \to a$, by definition of limits there exists $N$ such that $\forall n > N$: $|a_n - a| < \frac{a}{4}$ (go over the definition of the limit of a sequence if this is unclear). By the triangle inequality (check this yourself!) $a_n > \frac{3a}{4} > 0$, a contradiction. As such, we observe that $a \leq 0$.